# summing standardized or raw variables - does it matter?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution

I have 2 normal distributed variables, A and B that are correlated with a variable C in a linear regression. Because A and B  essentially measure the same latent variable I sum A and B, to increase power.

A and B differ in Standard deviation and mean so I thought to standardize them to a mean of zero and standard deviation of 1 before summing them up. However this does not change anything in the regression model (C~(A+B) vs C~(stdA+stdB)) , the P-value stays the same before and after normalizing (except for the coefficent). Is this correct, why?

Answer (score 1):

In simple linear regression the t-values and consequently also the p-values are obtained using *standardized* regression coefficients: $t = b / SE_b$

That is, the regression coefficient is set in relation to its standard error. Since the transformation you did will affect the coefficients and its standard error equally, their ratio will not change - so neither will the t-value.
In multiple regression the situation is similar.

See this for more detail: http://www.jerrydallal.com/lhsp/slrout.htm

With that said, standardizing your variables *will* affect the interpretation of your coefficients. For example, centralizing will change the meaning of the intercept, which [can be desirable](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/center-on-the-mean/).